# C#: Read Excel file failed with cell format look like number

Tags: c#, excel, string, datatable, numbers

I use this function to read excel file to datatable:

```
public static DataTable exceldata(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
            bool hasHeaders = false;
            string HDR = hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No";
            string strConn;
            if (filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
            else
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
            conn.Open();
            DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            DataRow schemaRow = schemaTable.Rows[0];
            string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
            {
                string query = "SELECT  * FROM [" + sheet + "]";
                OleDbDataAdapter daexcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
                dtexcel.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                daexcel.Fill(dtexcel);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return dtexcel;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My trouble is: When Excel file have some cells that format look like number (ex: 301/1, 181/3 .... ), the datatable return empty value in that cells.
How can read Excel files to datatable that cells as string, not number detected ?

Comment: try formatting the underlying excel as Text

Comment: Can you attach that spreadsheet (via DropBox or G-drive or something)?  I believe you but I've never seen and couldn't replicate that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've specifically asked to use an excel sheet. As someone who has faced the exact same issue, I would recommend you to use ClosedXML instead of using an Oledb connection.

Closed XML is much faster to read and allows you to get contents of an entire sheet or a cell very easily.

I've answered another question similar to this one here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235686/6729097